# D3 v4 Scatterplot chart data points are not updating on zoom

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am working on scatter-plot chart with `d3 v4` and wanted to apply zooming so that I can see the data points when they overlap each other, the problem I am facing here is both `x` and `y` axis are working fine but data points are not updating for some reason.

I am trying to select the dots/circles and draw them again but for some reason I couldn't select them, I have no clue why the dots are not updating, any help is much appreciated.

**Note:** my application is in `Angular 4`, since I couldn't find the `angular 2/4` template here in plunker I had to do in `JavaScript`.

Comment: Followed this link ->https://bl.ocks.org/aleereza/d2be3d62a09360a770b79f4e5527eea8 and plunker -> https://plnkr.co/edit/bNGwK3?p=preview

Comment: Emphasized few terms, text split to few paragraphs to increase readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed 2 minor things:

1. In the **zoom** function, the scales to be used would be the *new X and Y scales*, as you've to transform the circles in the new domain.

   ```
   circles.attr('cx', (d) => xNewScale(d.duration))
      .attr('cy', (d) => yNewScale(d.priority));
   ```
2. **Selection**:

   ```
   var circles = svg.selectAll('dot')
     .data(chartData)
     ....
     .append('svg:title')
     .html(...)
   ```

would actually return the "titles" as the current selection and so now, the variable **circles** is a node group of titles whose attributes (cx and cy) get changed in the zoom function which is not what we want as we want to change the attributes of the `<circle>`s. And so, changing the above to the following:

```
// Add the scatterplot
var circles = svg.selectAll("dot")
  .data(chartData)
  .enter()
  ....
  .attr('fill' ..);

// NOTE THE CHANGE HERE
circles
  .append('svg:title')
  .html(d => {
    return 'Date : ' + timeFormat(new Date(d.start)) + ',<br> Description: ' + d.description + ',<br> Impact: ' + d.priority + ',<br> Hours: ' + Math.round(d.duration)
  });
```

Similarly, I've made changes to the red circles (outer).

Comprising all of the above, here's a fork of your code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/61zf86q6cpIT4MIyhZKo?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good eye Shashank!, fresh eyes helps and saves lot of time, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)